# F# - Property 'ParameterSetName' is not static

Tags: powershell, f#, powershell-cmdlet

I write a PowerShell function in F# with four parameters.

```
[<Parameter(
  Mandatory=true,
  ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=true)>]
[<ValidateNotNullOrEmpty>]
member val Payload : Hashtable = Hashtable () with get, set
[<Parameter(
  Mandatory=true,
  ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=true)>]
member val Type : string = String.Empty with get, set
[<Parameter(
  ParameterSetName="Key",
  Mandatory=true,
  ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=true)>]
[<ValidateNotNullOrEmpty>]
member val Secret : string = String.Empty with get, set
[<Parameter(
  ParameterSetName="FilePath",
  Mandatory=true,
  ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=true)>]
[<ValidateNotNullOrEmpty>]
member val FilePath : System.IO.FileInfo = null with get, set
```

Ideally, I would like to use `match` for the ParameterSetNames but I get the error/warning that this property is no static.
`Property 'ParameterSetName' is not static`

To clarify what I mean by using `match`. I've got this code

```
let result = 
  match PSCmdlet.ParameterSetName with
    | "Key" -> newSecretWithContent x.Algorithm x.Payload x.Secret
    | "FilePath" -> newJwtWithFile x.Algorithm x.Payload x.FilePath.FullName
    | _ -> "Incorrect ParameterSet selected."
```

and the compiler gives me this warning:

```
Property 'ParameterSetName' is not static F# Compiler (806)
```

Comment: Not sure it’s the reason for this error, but `match` is a reserved keyword in F#. I would have expected a different error, though.

Comment: @Abel, I have updated my question to clarify what I mean by matching the ParameterSetName.

Comment: Thanks. Like Tomas, I’ve never used the cmdlets, interesting though! Showing the failing code helps :).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have never written a PowerShell cmdlet, but it seems that `PSCmdlet.ParameterSetName` refers to an instance member of the `PSCmdlet` class (see [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.pscmdlet.parametersetname?view=powershellsdk-7.2.0#system-management-automation-pscmdlet-parametersetname)). In PowerShell, you seem to be able to write `$PSCmdlet.ParameterSetName` because `$PSCmdlet` refers to the current cmdlet.

In F#, the current cmdlet is your "this" instance, i.e. `x`. According to the documentation, you can write cmdlets either by inheriting from `Cmdlet` or by deriving from `PSCmdlet` which gives you access to more of the runtime. If you dervie from `PSCmdlet`, you should be able to refer to this via `x` and write:

```
let result = 
  match x.ParameterSetName with
    | "Key" -> newSecretWithContent x.Algorithm x.Payload x.Secret
    | "FilePath" -> newJwtWithFile x.Algorithm x.Payload x.FilePath.FullName
    | _ -> "Incorrect ParameterSet selected."
```

Comment: Thank you very much! That was indeed the solution.